# Xcode 10.1 - Simulator crash attempting to present SKStoreProductViewController in landscape iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone XR, and iPhone XS Max

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, storekit

The following code loads in the simulator on iPhone 5S, iPhone 8, iPhone X, and iPhone XS, and all iPads.

The code also loads on a physical 8 Plus device.

The code crashes in the simulator for iPhone XR, XS Max, and 8 Plus.

This error message appears in addition to the crash on those simulator sizes: "`[Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x615000095e00, UIView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`"

Here is the code:

```
let storeViewController:SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();
storeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
storeViewController.delegate = self;

self.present(storeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);

var productparameters = [String : String]()

productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:appID, SKStoreProductParameterAffiliateToken:"123abc", SKStoreProductParameterProviderToken:"123456", SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken:campaignName];

storeViewController.loadProduct(withParameters: productparameters, completionBlock: { (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
            })
```

I also occasionally get this error message after the crash:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've tried it on two different Macs and after restarting Xcode and cleaning the build folder but it consistently crashes on XR, XS Max, and Plus devices in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the simulator doesn't have the App Store, StoreKit is not available on the simulator. It requires a physical device.

Of course, it shouldn't crash probably. But that sounds like a bug with Apple's code. Probably would be best to report it to them directly for that.

Running on an actual physical device should work tho!

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it is working on every physical device that I have tested on, but I don't have a physical XR or XS Max to test with. The app itself never loads in the simulator (because StoreKit isn't available) but it loads a blank App Store screen with a "cancel" button at top left on 7 of the 9 different simulator device sizes. On these other 2 device sizes (XR/XSMax and Plus) it crashes. =/

Comment: @RanLearns Oh yeah, really sounds like an Apple bug then. Nothing you can really do except report it.

Comment: Alright, thanks again for chiming in. Wasted way too much time trying to find a cause for the simulator crash here but I'll assume it is working as intended. Filed bug report #46964412 with Apple.

Comment: @RanLearns Awesome! Yeah I don't seen any red flags with your code or reasons why it'd be happening other than a bug with Apple and the fact that StoreKit isn't supported on the simulator. I don't see any reason that it's not a bug in Apple's systems.